# Loading pages of a website in different threads

Tags: c#, multithreading

For example, i can load the website 10 times consequentially with different pages (stackoverflow.com/questions/a , stackoverflow.com/questions/b , ...). The question is, will it be faster if i will load pages in 10 threads?

Comment: Best answer in all these things.. Try it and see.. a number of things can effect your answer - such as, if you only had a 1mb connection, you may max out the connection.. but, try it.. always the best thing

Comment: in the question title you write that you want to load the same page in 10 threads, in the description you write that you want to load 10 different pages - so it is not clear what exactly do you want to do

Comment: is it possible to load pages simultaneously from the same ip and port?

Comment: Yes. try it.. Thats the fun of learning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest time in loading a webpage is waiting for the HTTP response to come back from the server, and a large amount of that time is taken in setting up the TCP connection.

HTTP has supported the concept of [pipelining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_pipelining) since version 1.1. This allows multiple requests to be sent along the same TCP connection, and also allows them to be sent before the replies have come back from the previous requests.

So yes, using ten threads could speed up loading ten different pages, but equally one thread could do the same by using asynchronous calls and firing off ten requests before the replies come back.